# Changing the plot title in ngspice

Tags: spice, analysis

I'm hitting a snag plotting some data with ngspice.  I'm not sure of the syntax to use to add a title.  According to the user manual:

```
General Form:
plot exprs [ylimit ylo yhi] [xlimit xlo xhi] [xindices xilo xihi]
[xcompress comp] [xdelta xdel] [ydelta ydel] [xlog] [ylog] [loglog]
[vs xname] [xlabel word] [ylabel word] [title word] [samep]
[linear]

The title argument is used in the place of the plot name at the bottom of the graph.
```

That syntax is a mouthful.  Dutifully using the above: `plot db(vo / vin) title Stage_1_Gain`.  No dice.  I'm not really seeing a title anywhere on my plots.  According to the manual, it should be on the bottom.  All I've got is my axis labels.  Is there a mistake in my syntax somewhere?

Edit:  Also no dice using a string, `plot db(vo / vin) title "Stage 1 Gain"`.

Answer (score 1):

The title argument is currently only supported in the MS Windows GUI plot window. Unfortunately is has never been implemented in the LINUX plot window. We will change that asap. In the meantime I will update the manual.